# Reflection in swift : How to dynamically create object in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am trying to write deserializer for swift (JSON to Swift objects)

for example my swift class

```
class ClassA : NSObject{
var objOne : String!
var objTwo : String!
} 

class ClassB : NSObject{
var objOneB : String!
var ClassList : Array<ClassA>!
}
```

My JSON

```
var jsonString = "{"objOneB":"1B",ClassList[{"objOne":"1","objTwo":"2"},{"objOne":"1s","objTwo":"2s"}]"
```

now I am try to create a function

```
var clasObj = ClassB()
classObj.ParseData(jsonString)
```

I am expecting output from this

```
println(classObj.objOneB) // 1B
```

I followed a JSON Model library , this lib is good. but this support only Objective-C data types,

then I try to create my own. but I don't know how to create dynamic objects with property name.

because , `property_getAttributes()` not giving the correct type and `NSClassFromString` not creating the object

I need plugin like https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel for swift.

Please suggest me some ideas :(

Comment: what's "creating dynamic objects with property name"? You create objects with properties the exact same way you would create an object that has no properties.

Comment: [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) is a good JSON library written in Swift.

Comment: Just use `NSJSONSerialization` to create an object (array or dictionary depending on the top JSON object). They write code to work down the tree of objects.

Comment: Since JSON is built into Objective-C (and therefore Swift) there's little sense in using a 3rd party library to do it anymore.

Comment: Thank you for reply , i am try to implement like what c# serialization and deserialization methods. so i am not like to get values by Dict["string"] .

Comment: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper , 

https://github.com/cdebortoli/JsonManagedObject-Swift ,

https://github.com/tomekc/SwiftJSONMapper ,

https://github.com/kam800/SwiftMapper , https://github.com/jspahrsummers/Crust

Comment: JSONModel does a really good job for objective-c. Although there are some libraries for swift aswell they are not as "powerful" as JSONModel in my opinion. ObjectMapper looks good but still compared to JSONModel you need a lot more code to do the same thing.

Comment: I literally just had the same thought. Newtonsoft is a much better implementation and I was going to attempt to make a swift version but I think its missing vital language features.

I went in knowing its missing attributes and reflection but the more I poke the more I start to miss c#